# How to get the public product url for simple products (not visible individually)

Tags: magento-1.9, url, product-urls, geturl

I am getting the 404 error every time I am trying to get the correct URL for a product. I want to go to the specific url for that product, is there a specific magento solution to do this? I tried with `addUrlRewrite` and `getProductUrl` or `getUrlPath`. Nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the products which have "not visible individually" are not displayed on the frontend. Its a default magento functionality.

Magento has functionality to make certain items not visible individually so you can, for example, take 6 products and turn it into 1 product where a customer can choose their options.
You then hide all the individual products, leaving only that one product visible on the site and reducing duplicate content issues.

So those individual pages never actually appear on the site. They are just created to allow Magento to pull inventory on those items from that configurable product.

I would get a 404 (and if I searched for it, nothing would come up) because as far as the world outside of Magento admin is concerned, that URL doesn't exist.

Comment: I already know that, I am sorry for not being clear enough. Is there a way to get the url or not?  I know about "not visible individually" and that the URL doesn't exist. I wanna know if there is a way to get through this or not?

Comment: how would you get the url when the url itself doesnt exist

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much for your time and quick reply.

Comment: How you get it? I use the extension RedirectSimpleProducts from Dan0sz, and the only way to use simple's urls is to change the visibility to catalog and again to not visible individually. It would be perfect to generate the urls for this visibility too

Answer (score 0):

Not visible individually products are not displayed on the frontend by default.

but if you really want to show product here is the way

You have to override `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product` goto  `initProduct()`
**at line no 303** comment below the line

```
   if (!$this->canShow($product)) {
        return false;
    }
```